# Generic repository pattern ASP NET CORE Web Api: using include with async

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have following problem. 
My exemplary models looks as follows:

```
public class FacilityType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Training 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityType FacilityType { get; set; } 
    public int FacilityTypeID { get; set; } 
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

When I create new object of training type, I want it to be returned by my API with not only FacilityTypeID but also FacilityType as object, serialized in JSON.

Structure of my project is as follows.
I have generic repository pattern which I use in my controllers

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: class, IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllEntities();
    Task<TEntity> GetEntityById(int id );
    Task CreateEntity(TEntity entity);
    Task UpdateEntity(int id, TEntity entity);
    Task DeleteEntity(int id);
}
public async Task<TEntity> GetEntityById(int id )
    {

        return await context.Set<TEntity>().Where(ent => ent.IsDeleted != true && ent.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

And what I try to accomplish is find a way how to include related facility type to training which I return in method below.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Training>> GetTraining(int id)
    {
         return await repository.GetEntityById(id);

    }
```

Thank you in advance for your contributions :)

P.S:

Is using predicates in methods parameter a good idea? Like this: 
And btw. how to call such method using for example include linq expression?

```
   public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetEntityById(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {

        //return await context.Set<TEntity>().Where(ent => ent.IsDeleted != true && ent.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return await context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: You have just noticed a heavy limitation when attempting to build a generic repository. I would suggest you not to use it but instead to leverage EntityFramework itself which already is a repository with its `DbSet<T>` types.

Comment: So there really is no way to walk it around somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

If you have the interface `IEntity` already implementing the property `Id`:

```cs
public async Task<T> Get<T>(int id, Expression<Func<T, object>> include) where T : class, IEntity
{
    using (var context = new AppContext())
    {
        return await context.Set<T>()
                           .AsNoTracking()
                           .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                           .Include(include)
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

To call this method:

```cs
var entity = await _context.Get<Training>(1, x => x.FacilityType);
```

### Option 2

Without the interface `IEntity` (more generic way):

```cs
public async Task<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> include) where T : class
{
    using (var context = new AppContext())
    {
        return await context.Set<T>()
                           .AsNoTracking()
                           .Where(predicate)
                           .Include(include)
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

To call this method:

```cs
var entity = await _context.Get<Training>(x => x.Id == 1, x => x.FacilityType);
```

Comment: Ok, I was somewhere around that, but I didn't know how to call that method. Anyway, is that something I should use on regular basis?

Comment: It is up to you, if the project contains too many different entities that requires similar operations then you can use generic approach. See [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/#generics-overview) for more details.